# CARET Package in R - createDataPartition() function not found?

Tags: r, r-caret

I am learning the CARET Package in R and I am trying to run to code in Max Kuhn's paper "A Short Introduction to the caret Package".  When I run the following code, after successfully installing CARET:

```
data(Sonar)
set.seed(107)
# The outcome data are needed, the percentage of data in the training set & the format of the results 
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y = Sonar$Class,p = .75, list = FALSE)
str(inTrain)
```

I get the following error that this function createDataPartition() is not found:

```
Error in createDataPartition(y = Sonar$Class, p = 0.75, list = FALSE) : 
  could not find function "createDataPartition"
> str(inTrain)
Error in str(inTrain) : object 'inTrain' not found
```

Any thoughts?

Best,

Mike

Comment: Did you load the caret library? `library(caret)`

Comment: I second @jjl's suggestion on checking if you've loaded the `caret` library. To make use of the library after installing it is to load it into the workspace so R can use it in that particular session.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but I double-checked my instalation of caret:

Comment: Thanks - it turns out that when loading caraet, there are a bunch of packages that I had to manually load:

Comment: install.packages("caret", dependencies = c("Depends", "Suggests"))
library(munsell)
library(ggplot2)
library(ModelMetrics)
library(recipes)
library(assertthat)
library(bindrcpp)
library(glue)
library(pkgconfig)
library(DEoptimR)
library(caret)

Comment: No acceptable answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... The solution:

In your shell go to `/var/folders/tn/f7md6x8j0b73tg9tp83hgm4r0000gn/T//RtmpChzV5D/downloaded_packages`

```
cd /var/folders/tn/f7md6x8j0b73tg9tp83hgm4r0000gn/T//RtmpChzV5D/downloaded_packages
```

Look what you have there:

```
ls
```

If you have something like `caret_6.0-80.tgz`, you need to remove it:

```
sudo rm -r caret_6.0-80.tgz
```

I hope I've helped :)